# Strange Java null behavior in Method Overloading

Tags: java, null, overloading

I have the following code snippet:

```
public static void foo(Object x) {
    System.out.println("Obj");
}
public static void foo(String x) {
    System.out.println("Str");
}
```

If I call `foo(null)` why is there no ambiguity? Why does the program call `foo(String x)` instead of `foo(Object x)`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> why the program calls `foo(String x)` instead of `foo(Object x)`

That is because `String` class extends from `Object` and hence is more specific to `Object`. So, compiler decides to invoke that method. Remember, Compiler always chooses the most specific method to invoke. See [Section 15.12.5 of JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

However, if you have two methods with parameter - `String`, and `Integer`, then you would get `ambiguity` error for `null`, as compiler cannot decide which one is more specific, as they are non-covariant types.

Answer (score 5):

1. The type of `null` is by definition a **subtype of every other reference type**. Quote JLS 4.1:

   > The null reference can always undergo a widening reference conversion to any reference type.
2. The resolution of the method signature involved in an invocation follows the principle of the **most specific signature** in the set of all compatible signatures. (JLS 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method).

Taken together this means that the `String` overload is chosen in your example.

Answer (score 4):

It's calling the [*most specific*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) method.

Since String is a subclass of Object, String is "more specific" than Object.

Answer (score 2):

When given a choice between two methods where the argument is valid for both parameters, the compiler will always choose the most specific parameter as a match. In this case, `null` is a literal that can be handled as an `Object` and a `String`. `String` is more specific and a subclass of `Object` so the compiler uses it.