# Why this behavior in overloading

Tags: java

When I run this program why it is calling method overloaded with string parameter.

```
public class StaticBindTest {

    public static void main(String args[])  {
       StaticBindTest et = new StaticBindTest();
       et.sort(null);

    }

    //overloaded method
    public void sort(Object c){
        System.out.println("Inside Collection sort method");
    }


   //another overloaded method
    public void sort(String hs){
        System.out.println("Inside HashSet sort method");
    }

}
```

In case if I re-write my method as

```
    public void sort(String hs){
        if(hs instanceof String)
        System.out.println("Inside HashSet sort method");
    }
```

It will display blank console, which means it is not a instance of String then why it call in this manner?

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789478/strange-java-null-behavior-in-method-overloading

Comment: Also see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t's because In case of method Overloading

```
The most specific method is choosen at compile time.
```

As 'java.lang.String' is a more specific type than 'java.lang.Object'. In your case the method which takes 'String' as a parameter is choosen.

Clearly mentioned in [**DOCS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf)

Comment: In case if I declare another overloaded method with Integer type that it is giving me ambiguity error at compile time only. Why is it so.

Comment: @HyperLink because then it *is* ambiguous which one is the "most specific".  At the moment, `String` is a subclass of `Object` so out of the two it's clearly more specific.  But if you add `Integer` into the mix, is that more or less specific than `String`?  They're not in the same hierarchy so it's impossible to say.  And so Java cannot determine which is the most specific method.

Comment: how can i call the least specific method ??

Answer (score 1):

When I execute your code, I found `Inside HashSet sort method` is in output. `null` is empty reference to object. Both methods have Object as input that is why the method with more narrow hierarchy `String` is called. 
Do not write  `StaticBindTest et = new StaticBindTest();` 
Just call `sort(null)` without object `et`.

Answer (score 0):

The full methodology is explained in [section 15.12.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), and in particular 15.12.2.5 (choosing the most specific).

The summary is that Java always chooses the most specific overload that is applicable.  Since `null` can be an instance of any class, both methods are candidates.  And since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, it is definitely more specific.  Hence the String overload is called.

As for your closing paragraph, `null` is not an `instanceof` anything.  If you had written your Object-overload method in a similar way, it *also* would not have printed anything - so this is not strong evidence as to whether Java should have chosen one overload or another.

Comment: In case if I declare another overloaded method with Integer type that it is giving me ambiguity error at compile time only. Why is it so.