# Method overloading and null keyword

Tags: java

It would be great if anyone can explain below. Why `print(String s)` method is called in below example and `print(Object o)` not called.

```
package com.example;

public class DemoTest {

    public void print(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
    public void print(String s){
        System.out.println("String");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoTest dt = new DemoTest();
        dt.print(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a follup but what if there was a `print(Integer i)` method.  Then what would be chosen?  Or is that an error?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Strange Java null behavior in Method Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789478/strange-java-null-behavior-in-method-overloading)

"That is because String class extends from Object and hence is more specific to Object. So, compiler decides to invoke that method. Remember, Compiler always chooses the most specific method to invoke."

Comment: You could have just linked it...