# How do overloaded methods work?

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class Test1  {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        test1.testMethod(null);
    }

    public void testMethod(String s){
        System.out.println("Inside String Method");     
    }

    public void testMethod(Object o){
        System.out.println("Inside Object Method"); 
    }
}
```

When I try to run the given code, I get the following output:

> Inside String Method

Can anyone explain why the method with the `String` type parameter is getting called?

Comment: +1 It looked like super easy question, but using null... That's interesting indeed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange Java null behavior in Method Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789478/strange-java-null-behavior-in-method-overloading)

Comment: @RohitJain that question is already a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java)

Answer (score 19):

**most specific method argument is chosen for overloaded methods**

In this case, `String` is subclass of `Object`. Hence `String` becomes more specific than `Object`. Hence `Inside String method` is printed.

Directly from [JLS-15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

As BMT and LastFreeNickName have correctly suggested, `(Object)null` will cause overloaded method with `Object` type method to be called.

Comment: But for null, String and Object both are at the Same level , then how String can be more specific ?

Comment: Fully correct! You can try and pass (Object)null as parameter and it will choose the other method.

Comment: Whenever it encounters a string literal in your code, the compiler creates a `String object` with its value—in this case, *Null*.

Comment: @BMT Eh? `null` isn't the value of any string literal (although `"null"` might be), and there is no string literal in the OP's code anyway. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to an existing reply, I'm not sure if this is because of a newer Java version since the question, but when I tried to compile the code with a method taking an Integer as a parameter instead of an Object, the code still did compile. However, the call with null as the parameter still invoked the String parameter method at run-time.

For example,

```
public void testMethod(int i){
    System.out.println("Inside int Method");     
}

public void testMethod(String s){
    System.out.println("Inside String Method");     
}
```

will still give the output:

```
Inside String Method
```

when called as:

```
test1.testMethod(null);
```

The main reason for this is because String does accept null as a value and int doesn't. So null is classified as a String Object.

Coming back to the question asked, The type Object is encounter only when a new object is created. This is done by either type casting null as an Object by

```
test1.testMethod((Object) null);
```

or using any type of object for a primitive data type such as

```
test1.testMethod((Integer) null);
    or
test1.testMethod((Boolean) null);
```

or by simply creating a new object by

```
test1.testMethod(new  Test1());
```

It should be noted that

```
test1.testMethod((String) null);
```

will again invoke the String method as this would create an object of type String.

Also,

```
test1.testMethod((int) null);
    and
test1.testMethod((boolean) null);
```

will give a compile time error since boolean and int do not accept null as a valid value and as int!=Integer and boolean!=Boolean.
Integer and Boolean type cast to Objects of type int and boolean.