# Which method will get invoked during overloading when null is passed

Tags: java, overloading

In the following program:

```
public class PolyEx1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    A refA = new A();
        refA.method1(null);
    }
}

class A {
    public void method1(Object o) {
        System.out.println("o");
    }

    public void method1(String str) {
        System.out.println("str");
    }
}
```

The output is "str", can someone explain me why str was printed? I am not able to understand this.

Comment: This is not polymorphism. It is overloadng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Rohit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789478/strange-java-null-behavior-in-method-overloading/14789492#14789492),

> That is because String class extends from Object and hence is more
>   specific to Object. So, compiler decides to invoke that method.
>   Remember, Compiler always chooses the most specific method to invoke.
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.
>
> However, if you have two methods with parameter - String, and Integer,
>   then you would get ambiguity error for null, as compiler cannot decide
>   which one is more specific, as they are non-covariant types.
>
> As described in Section [15.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) of JLS

Answer (score 1):

Java try to use the most specific applicable version of a method.

`String` extends `Object` and so the method using String as parameter is always called.

If you try to add a method that take an `Integer` input it will throws error as ambiguous methods, because `String` and `Integer` both of them are more specific than Object but none is more specific than the other one

Answer (score 0):

public void method1(String str) will get executed because object is string supperclass so the string method will be called.

Comment: Great, why? That answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Tenner I updated the explanation. sorry for not reading the question carefully.would you please reconsider rating my answer